# on hover show image but at the same time don't hide background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a map and I want that when i hover a continent, he appears but also at the same time not to hide background.

this is my code :

```html
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-08-31-103251" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/58808/60863-ue1h8277se3mkfllaet1lledi0_worldmap.png" border="0" width="908" height="494" orgWidth="908" orgHeight="494" usemap="#image-maps-2015-08-31-103251" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2015-08-31-103251" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2015-08-31-103251">
 
<area  alt="North America" title="North America" href="http://www.google.com" shape="poly" coords="178,249,117,207,98,156,46,104,121,59,158,61,240,41,396,22" style="outline:none;" target="_blank" onclick="window.open("http://www.google.com");" onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-08-31-103251').src= 'http://i.imgur.com/B9N2Zbv.png';" onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-08-31-103251').src= 'http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/58808/60863-ue1h8277se3mkfllaet1lledi0_worldmap.png';"  />
```

I am not using any css, and this is only code. North America (black pic) is  a .png and its transparent by default.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: The problem right here is that you are using an image which you later replace bases on the mouse's coordinates. You would have to put the whole map as a background image on the <img> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to set the world map on a divider as a background image.

And mapping a transparent png the image map.

## Example

```
<div style="width:908;height:494px;background: url(http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/58808/60863-ue1h8277se3mkfllaet1lledi0_worldmap.png) no-repeat top center">

<img id="id-of-the-image" src="path-to-transparent-image-with-the-same-size-of-themap" border="0" width="908" height="494" />
```

Here's a link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLvu9muh/2/) based on your html,

> Stretch the fiddle result container for better display      .....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2015-08-31-103251').src= 'http://i.imgur.com/B9N2Zbv.png';
```

You are replacing the image source with the updated one so it is going to display the new image of the continent. Similarly with `onmouseout`

Comment: So i just have to remove it or can i actually make them show at the same time ? like first load background and then continent?

Comment: You cannot show them at the same time with the code you have. Try suggestion from Steyn's comment